# Design an addressing scheme, using VLSM?

Tags: networking, ip-address, subnet

If this has been asked before then I'm sorry.

I've been given this question and have been trying all weekend to figure it out. I've looked at multiple websites but none of them explain the process. It's really frustrating me. Can anyone help? So I've been given the first two pictures below. I'm just hoping someone could maybe explain this to me? I need to practice this for my exam!

[image: VLSM]

[image: Chart]

Comment: It's easy, work your way down from the network with the most hosts. 95 hosts = subnet mask of /25 (126 usable), 36 hosts = subnet mask of /26 (62 usable) and 20 hosts = subnet mask of /27 (30 usable). You can use /31 networks for the router links.

Comment: @CustomX for the links. Let’s say the R1-R2, does it not require 2 hosts?

Comment: Yes, /31 provides 2 addresses.

Comment: @CustomX but with the network address and 2 hosts addresses it will need 3 no?

Comment: As in /30 has 2^2-2 usable hosts. Which equates to 2 usable hosts which is required for the links?

Comment: Yes, but for point to point connections between routers and switches, you can use a /31.